# I have used softmax function with loss='binary_crossentropy' for a two class classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, loss-function, image-classification

for two class classification problem sigmoid + binary_crossentropy is fine  or softmax + categorical_crossentropy is fine. But in my case I have used softmax(2 dense layers) + binary_crossentropy and trained a DL model.. Is this correct? Does the accuracy produced is genuine?

Please let me know if softmax(2 dense layers) + binary_crossentropy is correct or not.

Comment: No, it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The number of layers it's irrelevant at this stage. If you use `softmax` then it's either `categorical_crossentropy` or `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` depending whether you one-hot-encoded the targets or not. But there's no consistency between `softmax` output layer activation function and `loss='binary_crossentropy'` , output is likely to be whacky.

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')) #2 because it's a two class problem

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adagrad', #optimizer can be whatever works best
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Whether using `softmax` or `sigmoid` depends on your classification problem. Is it something like 'A vs NOT A' or 'A or B' . Plot the model performance, compare and drive conclusions.